# Why node-fetch and cURL get response with status 200 but python requests returns with 403?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, curl, http-status-code-403

I've opened the https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/ page and  then with the network tab in dev tools opened, pressed the "Next Week" button on the page. Then just copied the displayed query as `cURL`.

So now, when I running the following cURL request in the terminal:

```
curl 'https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/Service/getCalendarFilteredData' \
  -H 'authority: www.investing.com' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: en,en-US;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'cookie: adBlockerNewUserDomains=1665484384; udid=854d35ee786dd208ca53bbf8d7bf7190; adtech_uid=cdd38139-1087-4a82-a10d-fad09c89cbc0%3Ainvesting.com; top100_id=t1.-1.1109927342.1665484387569; last_visit=1665448387571%3A%3A1665484387571; t3_sid_NaN=s1.1184232784.1665484387571.1665484387587.1.1.1.1; tmr_lvid=f04c2ffb9543f5d52eccf7ab9376872d; tmr_lvidTS=1665484391416; _ym_uid=1665484391864483144; _ym_d=1665484391; tmr_reqNum=6; PHPSESSID=255atufalen6v0k4qnm8834m89; geoC=RU; browser-session-counted=true; user-browser-sessions=2; gtmFired=OK; __cflb=02DiuGRugds2TUWHMkimMbdK71gXQtrngzLrqXfiyUNYt; protectedMedia=2; pms={"f":2,"s":2}; adbBLk=1; _gid=GA1.2.1570303324.1667159192; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; r_p_s_n=1; reg_trk_ep=exit popup banner; editionPostpone=1667159197680; adsFreeSalePopUp=3; g_state={"i_p":1667169060380,"i_l":1}; smd=854d35ee786dd208ca53bbf8d7bf7190-1667168108; _gat_allSitesTracker=1; nyxDorf=OD9jMWY3MnA3YGBpZzRkeGUzMm4zKmFiZ28yOA%3D%3D; __cf_bm=V0D5VdMcp0eoiZG09KZUp_tuvMOerNYlUUkgC48hGQk-1667168113-0-AU9O3zSc5YHozPL5pThX0RnGWfv7y5jGWWuHR7Ks/YT0vl6rO77feB/ngjSJj+4b/igviY+N8TXpBZbbh+BFoXA=; _gat=1; invpc=9; _ga_C4NDLGKVMK=GS1.1.1667168113.2.1.1667168114.59.0.0; _ga=GA1.1.1494444067.1665484391; outbrain_cid_fetch=true' \
  -H 'origin: https://www.investing.com' \
  -H 'referer: https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' \
  --data-raw 'country%5B%5D=25&country%5B%5D=32&country%5B%5D=6&country%5B%5D=37&country%5B%5D=72&country%5B%5D=22&country%5B%5D=17&country%5B%5D=39&country%5B%5D=14&country%5B%5D=10&country%5B%5D=35&country%5B%5D=43&country%5B%5D=56&country%5B%5D=36&country%5B%5D=110&country%5B%5D=11&country%5B%5D=26&country%5B%5D=12&country%5B%5D=4&country%5B%5D=5&timeZone=8&timeFilter=timeRemain&currentTab=nextWeek&limit_from=0' \
  --compressed
```

it returns me the response with status 200 and data I actually expected to get.

Then I converted it to Node.js fetch() using Postman and run the given using `node-fetch` As a result I get the successful 200 response also:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

fetch('https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/Service/getCalendarFilteredData', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'authority': 'www.investing.com',
        'accept': '*/*',
        'accept-language': 'en,en-US;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'cookie': 'adBlockerNewUserDomains=1665484384; udid=854d35ee786dd208ca53bbf8d7bf7190; adtech_uid=cdd38139-1087-4a82-a10d-fad09c89cbc0%3Ainvesting.com; top100_id=t1.-1.1109927342.1665484387569; last_visit=1665448387571%3A%3A1665484387571; t3_sid_NaN=s1.1184232784.1665484387571.1665484387587.1.1.1.1; tmr_lvid=f04c2ffb9543f5d52eccf7ab9376872d; tmr_lvidTS=1665484391416; _ym_uid=1665484391864483144; _ym_d=1665484391; tmr_reqNum=6; PHPSESSID=255atufalen6v0k4qnm8834m89; geoC=RU; browser-session-counted=true; user-browser-sessions=2; gtmFired=OK; smd=854d35ee786dd208ca53bbf8d7bf7190-1667159184; __cflb=02DiuGRugds2TUWHMkimMbdK71gXQtrngzLrqXfiyUNYt; protectedMedia=2; pms={"f":2,"s":2}; adbBLk=1; _gid=GA1.2.1570303324.1667159192; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; r_p_s_n=1; reg_trk_ep=exit popup banner; editionPostpone=1667159197680; adsFreeSalePopUp=3; g_state={"i_p":1667169060380,"i_l":1}; nyxDorf=NjEzYTZnPnw3YGlgZTZkeDFnZTkwKTc0Z283PQ%3D%3D; invpc=8; _ga=GA1.2.1494444067.1665484391; _ga_C4NDLGKVMK=GS1.1.1667159192.1.1.1667163056.58.0.0; __cf_bm=LZnYBJVRJi928k7wJrU_OYCihg_5tLR.QfD1zQuhlQg-1667163400-0-ARPOKPmQDZ71FgF5T4GwEDGP1VfBjG/9M7ke9oQE2LLqBxC/l23hb3U2JJW9Uki2IXspQXO1sg2YG6Va3rihdYU=',
        'origin': 'https://www.investing.com',
        'referer': 'https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    },
    body: 'country%5B%5D=25&country%5B%5D=32&country%5B%5D=6&country%5B%5D=37&country%5B%5D=72&country%5B%5D=22&country%5B%5D=17&country%5B%5D=39&country%5B%5D=14&country%5B%5D=10&country%5B%5D=35&country%5B%5D=43&country%5B%5D=56&country%5B%5D=36&country%5B%5D=110&country%5B%5D=11&country%5B%5D=26&country%5B%5D=12&country%5B%5D=4&country%5B%5D=5&timeZone=8&timeFilter=timeRemain&currentTab=nextWeek&limit_from=0'
})
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => console.log(data))
```

But Python requests library returns with 403 response:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/Service/getCalendarFilteredData"

payload='country%5B%5D=25&country%5B%5D=32&country%5B%5D=6&country%5B%5D=37&country%5B%5D=72&country%5B%5D=22&country%5B%5D=17&country%5B%5D=39&country%5B%5D=14&country%5B%5D=10&country%5B%5D=35&country%5B%5D=43&country%5B%5D=56&country%5B%5D=36&country%5B%5D=110&country%5B%5D=11&country%5B%5D=26&country%5B%5D=12&country%5B%5D=4&country%5B%5D=5&timeZone=8&timeFilter=timeRemain&currentTab=nextWeek&limit_from=0'
headers = {
  'authority': 'www.investing.com',
  'accept': '*/*',
  'accept-language': 'en,en-US;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'cookie': 'adBlockerNewUserDomains=1665484384; udid=854d35ee786dd208ca53bbf8d7bf7190; adtech_uid=cdd38139-1087-4a82-a10d-fad09c89cbc0%3Ainvesting.com; top100_id=t1.-1.1109927342.1665484387569; last_visit=1665448387571%3A%3A1665484387571; t3_sid_NaN=s1.1184232784.1665484387571.1665484387587.1.1.1.1; tmr_lvid=f04c2ffb9543f5d52eccf7ab9376872d; tmr_lvidTS=1665484391416; _ym_uid=1665484391864483144; _ym_d=1665484391; tmr_reqNum=6; PHPSESSID=255atufalen6v0k4qnm8834m89; geoC=RU; browser-session-counted=true; user-browser-sessions=2; gtmFired=OK; smd=854d35ee786dd208ca53bbf8d7bf7190-1667159184; __cflb=02DiuGRugds2TUWHMkimMbdK71gXQtrngzLrqXfiyUNYt; protectedMedia=2; pms={"f":2,"s":2}; adbBLk=1; _gid=GA1.2.1570303324.1667159192; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; r_p_s_n=1; reg_trk_ep=exit popup banner; editionPostpone=1667159197680; adsFreeSalePopUp=3; g_state={"i_p":1667169060380,"i_l":1}; nyxDorf=NjEzYTZnPnw3YGlgZTZkeDFnZTkwKTc0Z283PQ%3D%3D; invpc=8; _ga=GA1.2.1494444067.1665484391; _ga_C4NDLGKVMK=GS1.1.1667159192.1.1.1667163056.58.0.0; __cf_bm=LZnYBJVRJi928k7wJrU_OYCihg_5tLR.QfD1zQuhlQg-1667163400-0-ARPOKPmQDZ71FgF5T4GwEDGP1VfBjG/9M7ke9oQE2LLqBxC/l23hb3U2JJW9Uki2IXspQXO1sg2YG6Va3rihdYU=; __cf_bm=cpFWowJ_nrPc4KM6RjzSlo.xj9jfYCeD7otqZq1FQWQ-1667167043-0-AdUFidjpGSY5MUKCBuL6rcSsQ3w28YcFUzqxsqWE/h7iYoPA8nznX5QX62jyGu5UqnB6ZCBWrD/voQqIBgs8emQ=; adBlockerNewUserDomains=1667159926; firstUdid=0; smd=854d35ee786dd208ca53bbf8d7bf7190-1667159184; udid=854d35ee786dd208ca53bbf8d7bf7190; user-browser-sessions=1; PHPSESSID=255atufalen6v0k4qnm8834m89; __cflb=02DiuGRugds2TUWHMkimMbdK71gXQtrniHfGTE9vrV6rg; adsFreeSalePopUp=3; geoC=RU',
  'origin': 'https://www.investing.com',
  'referer': 'https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.status_code)
```

So, why Node.js and cURL get response with status 200 but python requests returns with 403? How to fix that? Because I actually need the python for my purposes.

Comment: Did you try them each multiple times? It could just be that the session token had expired by the time you tried Python.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I've tried all three requests multiple times and for example `node-fetch` still works over and over without any token updates needed. I also tried to convert cURL requests to python via `curlconverter.com` and perform `json.dumps` on payload object but this nothing changes too.

Comment: Looking at the body of the response, it would appear you're getting blocked by cloudflare. Likely they're trying to prevent automated use of the API. Error message is: `This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or malformed data.`

Comment: @NickODell if so it looks they don't do that right. Because `cURL`, `node-fetch` and `postman` requests works.

Comment: Well, blocking bots is not an exact science. Sometimes there is no way to tell apart automated and manual traffic in a way that doesn't result in collateral damage to real users.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because of cookies. Did you try removing cookies? Specially the 'g_state' cookie.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33793074)

Answer (score -2):

No Luck bro. i have tried it in curlconverter as well but have not able to run it yet. But if you are using any unix systems , you can try running the below code though. (If windows, you can anyway use [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/install.html))

```
#One option:
import os
result = os.popen('''curl 'https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/Service/getCalendarFilteredData' \
  -H 'authority: www.investing.com' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: en,en-US;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'cookie: adBlockerNewUserDomains=1665484384; udid=854d35ee786dd208ca53bbf8d7bf7190; adtech_uid=cdd38139-1087-4a82-a10d-fad09c89cbc0%3Ainvesting.com; top100_id=t1.-1.1109927342.1665484387569; last_visit=1665448387571%3A%3A1665484387571; t3_sid_NaN=s1.1184232784.1665484387571.1665484387587.1.1.1.1; tmr_lvid=f04c2ffb9543f5d52eccf7ab9376872d; tmr_lvidTS=1665484391416; _ym_uid=1665484391864483144; _ym_d=1665484391; tmr_reqNum=6; PHPSESSID=255atufalen6v0k4qnm8834m89; geoC=RU; browser-session-counted=true; user-browser-sessions=2; gtmFired=OK; __cflb=02DiuGRugds2TUWHMkimMbdK71gXQtrngzLrqXfiyUNYt; protectedMedia=2; pms={"f":2,"s":2}; adbBLk=1; _gid=GA1.2.1570303324.1667159192; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; r_p_s_n=1; reg_trk_ep=exit popup banner; editionPostpone=1667159197680; adsFreeSalePopUp=3; g_state={"i_p":1667169060380,"i_l":1}; smd=854d35ee786dd208ca53bbf8d7bf7190-1667168108; _gat_allSitesTracker=1; nyxDorf=OD9jMWY3MnA3YGBpZzRkeGUzMm4zKmFiZ28yOA%3D%3D; __cf_bm=V0D5VdMcp0eoiZG09KZUp_tuvMOerNYlUUkgC48hGQk-1667168113-0-AU9O3zSc5YHozPL5pThX0RnGWfv7y5jGWWuHR7Ks/YT0vl6rO77feB/ngjSJj+4b/igviY+N8TXpBZbbh+BFoXA=; _gat=1; invpc=9; _ga_C4NDLGKVMK=GS1.1.1667168113.2.1.1667168114.59.0.0; _ga=GA1.1.1494444067.1665484391; outbrain_cid_fetch=true' \
  -H 'origin: https://www.investing.com' \
  -H 'referer: https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' \
  --data-raw 'country%5B%5D=25&country%5B%5D=32&country%5B%5D=6&country%5B%5D=37&country%5B%5D=72&country%5B%5D=22&country%5B%5D=17&country%5B%5D=39&country%5B%5D=14&country%5B%5D=10&country%5B%5D=35&country%5B%5D=43&country%5B%5D=56&country%5B%5D=36&country%5B%5D=110&country%5B%5D=11&country%5B%5D=26&country%5B%5D=12&country%5B%5D=4&country%5B%5D=5&timeZone=8&timeFilter=timeRemain&currentTab=nextWeek&limit_from=0' \
  --compressed''').read()
print(result)
```